# Shiny app ignores %>% piping into group_by(), mutate() and top_n()

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming, piping

**UPDATED** as per amrrs's answer.

I have a shiny app, with reproducible code below, for which I'm unable to figure out the proper reactive({}) reference calls. The error I get when I try to aggregate filtered data, and which I don't know how to get around, is

"*Error: attempt to select less than one element in get1index*"

The app has two tabs:

- TAB 1: **Data Filters**: user imports a csv (sample below); selects
  the columns to display on the plot; sliders are used to filter the data; a filtered scatter plot is displayed. Note that I avoided using `%>%` in my filter calls for `df_filt` because it would not work. Because I want my slider limits and default value to be based on the user-selected columns, I used renderUI({}) and uiOutput() which make the reference syntax somewhat cumbersome (e.g., `filedata()[[input$selectcol1]]`) - is this notation contributing to the error?

[image]

- TAB 2: **Summary Table**: should be an aggregated summary of the data that has been
  filtered in TAB 1: group_by() selected columns; mutate() to count the number of
  records; top_n() to find the top value within each group.

[image]
Below are my server and ui files:

**SERVER.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  filedata <- reactive({
    infile <- input$datafile
    if (is.null(infile)) {
      # User has not uploaded a file yet
      return(NULL)
    }
    temp<-read.csv(infile$datapath)
    #return
    temp[order(temp[, 1]),]
  })

  output$selectcol1 <- renderUI({
    df <-filedata()
    if (is.null(df)) return(NULL)

    items=names(df)
    names(items)=items
    selectInput("selectcol1", "Height",items)
  })

  output$selectcol2 <- renderUI({
    df <-filedata()
    if (is.null(df)) return(NULL)

    items=names(df)
    names(items)=items
    selectInput("selectcol2", "Width",items)
  })

  output$selectcol3 <- renderUI({
    df <-filedata()
    if (is.null(df)) return(NULL)

    items=names(df)
    names(items)=items
    selectInput("selectcol3", "Height x Width",items)
  })

  output$selectcol4 <- renderUI({
    df <-filedata()
    if (is.null(df)) return(NULL)

    items=names(df)
    names(items)=items
    selectInput("selectcol4", "Hover Text",items)
  })

  output$minheight <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("height","Min. Height", min = 0, 
                max = max(filedata()[[input$selectcol1]], na.rm=TRUE),
                value = min(filedata()[[input$selectcol1]], na.rm=TRUE)
    )})

  output$minwidth <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("width","Min. Width", min = 0, 
                max = max(filedata()[[input$selectcol2]], na.rm=TRUE),
                value = min(filedata()[[input$selectcol2]], na.rm=TRUE)
    )})

  output$heightxwidth <- renderUI({
        sliderInput("hxw","Height x Width", min = 0,
                    max = max(filedata()[[input$selectcol3]], na.rm=TRUE),
                    value = min(filedata()[[input$selectcol3]], na.rm=TRUE)
        )})

  df_filt <- reactive({
    filter(filedata(),filedata()[[input$selectcol1]]>input$height &
             filedata()[[input$selectcol2]]>input$width &
             filedata()[[input$selectcol3]]>input$hxw)
  })

    df_filt_top <- reactive({
      df_filt() %>% 
        group_by(df_filt()[[input$selectcol6]], df_filt()[[input$selectcol5]]) %>%
        mutate(NumberOfRecords = n(),
               maxHxW = max(df_filt()[[input$selectcol3]])) %>%
        ungroup() %>%
        group_by(df_filt()[[input$selectcol6]], df_filt()[[input$selectcol5]]) %>%
        top_n(1, df_filt()[[input$selectcol3]])
    })

      output$filedata = renderDataTable({
        df_filt_top()
    })

  output$distPlot <- renderPlotly({

    p <- ggplot() + 
      geom_point(data=filedata(), aes(filedata()[[input$selectcol1]],
                                      y=filedata()[[input$selectcol2]], 
                                      text=paste("M: ",filedata()[[input$selectcol4]])),
                 colour="green", alpha=0.35) +
      geom_point(data=df_filt(), aes(x=df_filt()[[input$selectcol1]],
                                       y=df_filt()[[input$selectcol2]],
                                       text=paste("M: ",df_filt()[[input$selectcol4]])),
                 colour="orange", alpha=0.5) +
      xlab("Height") + ylab("Width") +
      scale_y_log10() +
      scale_x_log10()

    ggplotly(p)

  })
})
```

**UI.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)


shinyUI(fluidPage(tabsetPanel(

  # Application title
  tabPanel("Data Filters", " ",
           fluidRow(
             titlePanel("Plot"),

             # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 fileInput('datafile', 'Choose CSV file',
                           accept=c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain')),
                 uiOutput("selectcol1"),
                 uiOutput("minheight"),
                 uiOutput("selectcol2"),
                 uiOutput("minwidth"),
                 uiOutput("selectcol3"),
                 uiOutput("heightxwidth"),
                 uiOutput("selectcol4"),
                 uiOutput("hovertext")

               ),

               # Show a plot of the generated distribution
               mainPanel(
                 plotlyOutput("distPlot")
               ))
           )),
  tabPanel("Summary Table", " ",
           fluidRow(
             titlePanel(h2("Aggregate Data"), br()),

             column(width = 3,
                    " ",
                    dataTableOutput('filedata'))
           ))
)))
```

**CSV sample**
FID,RecordName,ID_1,PrimaryType,ID_2,Status,ClassName,Width,Height,HeightxWidth,Mass
1,A,611922,Type_A,52308,Inactive,1,0.29,0.356,0.1032,0.9332
2,A,611923,Type_A,52308,Inactive,1,0.4,0.242,0.0968,0.9332
3,B,458938,Type_A,70863,Active,2,5,0.72,3.6,5.6225
4,B,458939,Type_A,70863,Active,2,1,2.06,2.06,5.6225
5,B,458940,Type_A,70863,Active,2,1,2.83,2.83,5.6225
6,B,458941,Type_A,70863,Active,2,1,1.14,1.14,5.6225
7,B,458942,Type_A,70863,Active,2,3,1.24,3.72,5.6225
8,B,458943,Type_A,70863,Active,2,1,4.3,4.3,5.6225
9,B,458944,Type_A,70863,Active,2,1.2,2.73,3.276,5.6225
10,B,458945,Type_A,70863,Active,2,56.5,0.41,23.165,5.6225
11,B,458946,Type_A,70863,Active,2,15,1,15,5.6225
12,B,462017,Type_A,70863,Active,2,1,12.06,12.06,5.6225
13,B,471678,Type_A,70863,Active,2,1,19.45,19.45,5.6225
14,B,471679,Type_A,70863,Active,2,3,1.05,3.15,5.6225
15,B,471680,Type_A,70863,Active,2,1,4.67,4.67,5.6225
16,B,471681,Type_A,70863,Active,2,2,1.6,3.2,5.6225
17,B,471682,Type_A,70863,Active,2,1,1.27,1.27,5.6225
18,B,471683,Type_A,70863,Active,2,1,1.93,1.93,5.6225
19,B,471684,Type_A,70863,Active,2,3,1.47,4.41,5.6225
20,B,471685,Type_A,70863,Active,2,1,1.06,1.06,5.6225
21,B,471686,Type_A,70863,Active,2,7.96,1.28,10.1888,5.6225
22,B,471687,Type_A,70863,Active,2,1.54,3.06,4.7124,5.6225
23,B,555816,Type_A,70863,Active,2,0.2,1.84,0.368,5.6225
24,B,555817,Type_A,70863,Active,2,0.15,6.1,0.915,5.6225
25,B,555818,Type_A,70863,Active,2,0.3,1.65,0.495,5.6225
26,B,555819,Type_A,70863,Active,2,0.2,9.39,1.878,5.6225
27,B,555820,Type_A,70863,Active,2,0.4,7.14,2.856,5.6225
28,B,555821,Type_A,70863,Active,2,0.25,3.22,0.805,5.6225
29,B,555822,Type_A,70863,Active,2,0.5,2.84,1.42,5.6225
30,B,555823,Type_A,70863,Active,2,0.4,7.34,2.936,5.6225
31,B,555824,Type_A,70863,Active,2,0.2,2.82,0.564,5.6225
32,B,555825,Type_A,70863,Active,2,0.35,7.23,2.5305,5.6225
33,B,555826,Type_A,70863,Active,2,0.2,1.05,0.21,5.6225
34,B,555827,Type_A,70863,Active,2,0.15,2.28,0.342,5.6225
35,B,555828,Type_A,70863,Active,2,0.4,1.23,0.492,5.6225
36,B,555829,Type_A,70863,Active,2,0.15,1.28,0.192,5.6225
37,C,58431,Type_A,25871,Active,3,3.14,6.67,20.9438,52.9908
38,C,58432,Type_A,25871,Active,3,1.96,10.83,21.2268,52.9908
39,C,58433,Type_A,25871,Active,3,0.21,4.16,0.8736,52.9908
40,C,58434,Type_A,25871,Active,3,0.21,16,3.36,52.9908
41,C,58435,Type_A,25871,Active,3,4.08,26.36,107.5488,52.9908
42,C,58436,Type_A,25871,Active,3,7.78,0.22,1.7116,52.9908
43,C,58437,Type_A,25871,Active,3,6.37,1.6,10.192,52.9908
44,C,58438,Type_A,25871,Active,3,3.35,3.4,11.39,52.9908
45,C,58439,Type_A,25871,Active,3,2.44,6.5,15.86,52.9908

Comment: Yes, that's the problem, you are trying to select the column name dynamically?

Comment: @amrrs: yes, user selects the columns that get plotted. User-selectwd columns have their max and min calculated for the sliders. What is the way to do this and have it be reactive for the aggregate table?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is at Line number 79 in Server.R

Your code: refers to the reactive object `df_filt`

`df_filt_top <- reactive({
      df_filt %>%`

which should be changed to calling that reactive expression with `df_filt()`:

`df_filt_top <- reactive({
      df_filt() %>%`

But looks like you'd face new issues down the line since the code is cluttered.

Comment: thanks - i think that was a typo....the new error is now: ERROR: attempt to select less than one element in get1index